# Declaring global variable inside a function

Tags: bash, shell, scope

What I want to do is following. Inside a function, I need to assign a value to a variable, whose name is taken from another variable. In other words:

```
func() {  
  #  
  # Here happens something that ultimately makes $arg="var_name"
  # 
  declare -g ${arg}=5
}

func

echo ${var_name}; # Prints out "5"
```

The code snippet above works great in bash 4.2. However, in bash before 4.2, `declare` doesn't have the `-g` option. Everything I found at google says that to define the global variable inside a function, I should just use the `var=value` syntax, but unfortunately `var` itself depends on another variable. `${arg}=5` doesn't work, either. (It says `-bash: var_name=5: command not found`.

For the curious, the reason for all this is that this function actually creates global variables from the script parameters, i.e. running `script --arg1=val` automatically creates variable named `arg1` with value `val`. Saves tons of a boilerplate code.

Comment: You could construct your var=value as a string and evaluate it using the bash builtin command `eval`.

Comment: @minopret Can you repost your comment as an answer? Unless someone comes up with a less hackish solution, I will just accept your answer, it definitely works.

Comment: > running `script --arg1=val` automatically creates variable named arg1 with value val

ermmm... can't you just run this like `arg1=val script` and it will be set for the duration of running the script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could construct your var=value as a string and evaluate it using the bash builtin command `eval`.

Comment: @sivann look at my answer

Comment: `eval var=\"value with a space\"` if you need to use quotes, they must be escaped

Answer (score 19):

`declare` inside a function doesn't work as expected.
I needed read-only global variables declared in a function.
I tried this inside a function but it didn't work:

```
declare -r MY_VAR=1
```

But this didn't work. Using the `readonly` command did:

```
func() {
    readonly MY_VAR=1
}
func
echo $MY_VAR
MY_VAR=2
```

This will print 1 and give the error "MY_VAR: readonly variable" for the second assignment.

Comment: Using `declare -rg` should work as well. From the docs: "When used in a function, 'declare' makes NAMEs local, as with the 'local' command.  The '-g' option suppresses this behavior."

Answer (score 10):

I think you need the `printf` builtin with its `-v` switch:

```
func() {
    printf -v "$var" '5'
}
var=var_name
func
echo "$var_name"
```

will output `5`.

Answer (score 8):

Since this is tagged `shell`, it is important to note that `declare` is a valid keyword only in a limited set of shells, so whether it supports -g is moot.  To do this sort of thing in a generic Bourne shell, you can just use eval:

```
eval ${arg}=5
```

Answer (score 5):

Using "eval" (or any direct assignment) can give you headaches with special characters (or issues with value injection etc).

I've had great success just using "read"

```
$ function assign_global() {
>   local arg="$1"
>   IFS="" read -d "" $arg <<<"$2"
>}
$ assign_global MYVAR 23
echo $MYVAR
23
$ assign_global MYVAR "\"'"
"'
```

Comment: But this appends a trailing newline to the variable…

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf - The given example will indeed append newline, but the example specifically addresses special characters (such as newlines) in the string being read.  If you are certain there will be no newlines etc in the argument being read, you can remove the -d option from read to read until, but not including, the first new line character.

Comment: I think this will work: `read -d"\0" $arg <<< "$2"`, with no need to change `IFS`

Answer (score 4):

If you want something a little less hackish, try using `export` in place of `declare -g`. It has the added benefit of being an environment variable now.

```
func() {  
#  
# Here happens something that ultimately makes $arg="var_name"
# 
export ${arg}=5
}

func

echo ${var_name}; # Prints out "5"
```

Unfortunately, this still does not work for arrays.

Comment: to work with arrays export will not work, you can look at my answer

Answer (score 4):

The existence of the `local` and `declare` builtin commands may render it counter-intuitive that the wanted functionality is actually available from the `export` builtin, at least on Bash.

According to the Bash manual, the `export` command has an `-n` option, which "*causes the export property to be removed from each name*". This also applies while declaring variables with values right ahead.

The following snippet demonstrates the usage:

```
VAR=old-value
function func () {
    export -n "$1=$2"
}
func VAR new-value
echo "VAR=$VAR"     # prints VAR=new-value
```

One may create one own's `global` function, and use it inside other functions:

```
VAR=old-value
function global () {
    export -n "$1=$2"
}
function main () {
    global VAR "$1"
}
main main-value
echo "VAR=$VAR"            # prints VAR=main-value
```

This is verified working on

- an old Bash 2.03.0(1) running on a (modern) OS/390 z/OS
- on a Bash 3.2.57(1) on macOS 10.15
- on a Bash 4.1.2(2) on CentOS 6

I used this to inspect the various possibilities:

```
#!env bash

export LANG=C LC_ALL=C

A=a0
B=b0
C=c0
D=d0
E=e0
export F=f0

function testfunc () {
    local "$1=$2"       ; shift 2
    declare "$1=$2"     ; shift 2
    declare -g "$1=$2"  ; shift 2
    export -n "$1=$2"   ; shift 2
    export "$1=$2"
}

echo "$A/$B/$C/$D/$E"
testfunc A a1 B b1 C c1 D d1 E e1
echo "$A/$B/$C/$D/$E"

export -p | grep -E '^declare -x [ABCDEF]='
```

In case of macOS 10.15 this shows an output similar to this:

```
$ bash test.sh
a0/b0/c0/d0/e0
test.sh: line 15: declare: -g: invalid option
declare: usage: declare [-afFirtx] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
a0/b0/c0/d1/e1
declare -x E="e1"
declare -x F="f0"
```

The output shows that the `local` and `declare` commands used in the `testfunc` function effectively do not apply the variables in the global context (as documented) and that the `declare -g` option is not widely supported yet. It also shows that the variables D and E have been changed in the global context from inside the `testfunc` function (as hoped for), while only the E variable has been marked for export as a side effect by the `export` command, showing that the `export -n` option is effective. The variable F is there just to verify the grep command worked as expected.

Answer (score 3):

In Bash for declaring array variables inside a function definition you can use the `local` command in combination with the `eval` command like in the following example:

```
#!/bin/bash
function test
{
    local -g $1
    local array=( AA BB 'C C' DD)
    eval ${1}='("${array[@]}")'
}
test VAR
echo VAR=${VAR[@]:1:2}
```

the output will be:

```
$./test.sh
VAR=BB C C
```

works with: GNU bash, Version 4.4.18

Comment: works with `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin18)` too

Comment: this takes advantage of the fact that `local` is a synonym for `declare`, but using `local -g` seems strange, as you're doing the opposite of local. I would use `declare -g` just to make it clear what's going on. From the docs: "When used in a function, 'declare' makes NAMEs local, as with the 'local' command.  The '-g' option suppresses this behavior."

Answer (score 0):

Eval will work with Array variables...I just had to single quote the local Array variable inside the eval statement.

The below reads in a file (1st arg) a line at a time and then copies it to the variable name passed to the 2nd arg of the get_file.

```html
get_file () {
  declare -a Array=();
  while read line; do
    Array=("${Array[@]}" "($line)")
  done < ${1}
  eval ${2}='("${Array[@]}")'
  unset Array
}

declare -a my_array=();
get_file /etc/myfile.conf my_array
echo ${#my_array[@]}
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement the `mapfile` builtin? `mapfile -t my_array < /etc/myfile.conf` will gladly do that for you, and more efficiently too.

Comment: Unfortunately this is for a Solaris 10 application which doesn't appear to include mapfile in that bash implementation.  So hence the kludge

Comment: `mapfile` is a Bash builtin, so OS is irrelevant. Bash version is relevant, though. `mapfile` appears in version 4 (which is already a few years old).

Comment: That would explain it.  The bash version on the system i'm using to test is an unpatched version 3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your could use the following functions to dynamically assign your global variable in bash(< 4.2). If > 2 args passed, then the value will be array type.
E.G

```
_set2globals variable_name arg1 [arg2] [arg3] [...]
```

Source:

```
# dynamically set $variable_name($1)=$values($2...) to globals scope
function _set2globals()
{
    if (( $# < 2 )); then
        printf "$FUNCNAME: expect at least 2 argument, but %d you given.\n" $# >&2
        exit 1
    fi
    local ___pattern_='^[_a-zA-Z][_0-9a-zA-Z]*$'
    if [[ ! $1 =~ $___pattern_ ]]; then
        printf "$FUNCNAME: invalid variable name: %s.\n" "$1" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
    local __variable__name__=$1
    shift
    local ___v_
    local ___values_=()
    while (($# > 0)); do
        ___v_=\'${1//"'"/"'\''"}\'
        ___values_=("${___values_[@]}" "$___v_") # push to array
        shift
    done

    eval $__variable__name__=\("${___values_[@]}"\)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`-g -r` does the job. My bash version is: 5.1.16. Here is an example:

```
function setup() {
    declare -g -r VERSION="${1:-2.0}"
}

function main() {
    setup "$@"
    VERSION="2.3" # error
}

main "$@"
```